# Missing SDP information in SIP OK after invite

Tags: pjsip, sdp, invite

I am using pjproject 2.7.2 and it works fine but i have one problem. I setup a call and then I send another invite with the attribute inactive. PjSip answers with a 200OK which is correct but the SDP information is not complete.

Invite:

```
Session Description Protocol
            Session Description Protocol Version (v): 0
            Owner/Creator, Session Id (o): - 2351622143 2351622137 IN IP4 10.17.87.101
            Session Name (s): sessionDescription
            Connection Information (c): IN IP4 10.17.87.101
            Time Description, active time (t): 0 0
            Media Description, name and address (m): audio 5000 RTP/AVP 8
            Connection Information (c): IN IP4 127.0.0.1
            Media Attribute (a): label:SDPlabelCtrl
            Media Attribute (a): inactive
            Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
            Media Description, name and address (m): audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
            Connection Information (c): IN IP4 127.0.0.1
            Media Attribute (a): label:SDPlabelCall_1
            Media Attribute (a): inactive
            Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:8 PCMA/800
```

SIP OK:

```
v=0
o=- 3753002766 3753002774 IN IP4 10.17.87.201
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 2000 RTP/AVP 8
c=IN IP4 10.17.87.201
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:2001 IN IP4 10.17.87.201
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=label:SDPlabelCtrl
a=inactive
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
```

So in the 200ok is the label SDPlabelCall_1 missing. Is there any easy way to add this in pjproject?
Thanks
BR
Harald

Comment: Are you sure you have read the complete packet?

Comment: Yes this information is from the wireshark trace!

Comment: Since the SDP answer's first media line contains the attributes you want I would try changing the SDP offer so that the second media line resembles the first. It might be the UAS then supplies these attributes for the second line too. So use a valid port instead of 0. Also I wouldn't use localhost IP but 10.17.87.101.

Comment: See RFC3264 chapter 8.4: "... the port number MUST NOT be zero, which would specify that the stream has been disabled." Don't use port number 0 when you just want to put the stream on hold.

Comment: When I set the port to a value not zero i got the complete SDP. But my problem is that the message is send from another tool so i am not able to change it.

Comment: That tool does not comply with RFC 3264 so you should seriously consider replacing it. Strange that it also formats the second media line differently (wrong) than the first. If you cannot replace the tool you will have to make (RFC-violating) changes to (the configuration of) your pjsip project.

Comment: I am not able to replace that tool but I found the following part. RFC 3264, section 5.1: "A port number of zero in the offer indicates that the stream is offered but MUST NOT be used"

Comment: Realize that not using a stream is NOT the same as putting a valid on hold.

Comment: Yes I understand that there is a different between not using (deactivate) and hold. Both cases are defined in the RFC but I was not able to figure out if it is ok that the sdp is not complete in case of a deactivation!? Is that somewhere defined?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it incomplete. If you disable a stream there is no need to convey all its information in the response.